# How do I get more charges of Psygate?

Tags: space-hulk-deathwing

As the librarian of the group I have an array of psi abilities with one of the most useful skills being that I can make a psygate in order to resupply and replenish.

It has a certain number of charges on it so you can't just keep casting it and basically be unstoppable. Usually, I'm hyperaware of how many charges I have on it and periodically I've noticed that I suddenly get an extra charge.

So far I don't know why I'm getting these extra charges as they've appeared at different parts of levels. **Why am I getting more charges of Psygate and how can I keep getting more?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Yes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/176349/yes) for answering this unintendedly in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/296227/what-does-willpower-do/297176#297176).

The reason I was getting more charges of Psygate was because I was filling my willpower bar up (by gathering relics and such). When the willpower bar is fully charged, it will grant a new charge of Psygate to be used.