# What does willpower do?

Tags: space-hulk-deathwing

Throughout my experience in Space Hulk: Deathwing, I've been paying attention to this little green bar besides my health and stamina that is apparently my willpower bar. So far, I haven't noticed it decrease (as I thought it might be like mana) during a level but, whenever I gather a relic, the bar increases based on how big a relic it is.

However, while I've noticed the bar levels changing, I don't know what willpower actually does.

How does willpower affect the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willpower will, when reaching a full bar, add 1 charge to your Psygate, allowing more moments of rest and rearming.